# Error returning IEnumerable<SelectListItem> to MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, ienumerable

Hi I have a business logic layer that returns selectlistitems to a controller, so that will then pass to the view to populate select lists.

I have this method that works:

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDevices
    {
      get
      {
        using (IDeviceData repository = _dataFactory.Create())
        {
          return repository.DeviceTypes.ToList()
            .Where(dt => dt.ParentId == 10 )
             .Select(dt =>
             new SelectListItem
             {
               Text = (dt.Name).Trim(),
               Value = dt.Id.ToString()
             });
        }
      }
    }
```

And this that doesn't:

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetGroups(int deviceTypeId)
    {
        using (IDeviceData repository = _dataFactory.Create())
        {
          return repository.DeviceTypeConfigurationParameterGroupMaps.ToList()
            .Where(cm => cm.DeviceTypeId == deviceTypeId)
            .Join(repository.ConfigurationParameterGroups, cm => cm.ConfigurationParameterGroupId, cg => cg.Id, (cm, cg) => new { cm, cg })
             .Select(cg =>
             new SelectListItem
             {
               Text = (cg.cg.Name).Trim(),
               Value = cg.cg.Id.ToString()
             });
        }
      }
```

The obvious difference is the join between two tables, the error I receieve is:

```
Results View = The type '<>f__AnonymousType0<p,d>' exists in both 'System.Web.dll' and 'EntityFramework.dll'
```

This is receieved when trying to expand the results whiel debugging. Any advice would eb welcome as I'm not overly familiar with LINQ

Comment: From what you posted it seems that both DLLs contain a definition of a type that matches your anonymous type created as `new { cm, cg }`. I suppose that if you created a helper class (or used one of the types that already exist) instead of using the anonymous one it might work

Comment: Thanks joanna, that was part of the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetGroupsForDevice(int deviceTypeId)
    {
        using (IDeviceData repository = _dataFactory.Create())
        {
          return repository.DeviceTypeConfigurationParameterGroupMaps
            .Where(cm => cm.DeviceTypeId == deviceTypeId)
            .Join(repository.ConfigurationParameterGroups, cm => cm.ConfigurationParameterGroupId, cg => cg.Id, (cm, cg) =>  cg )
            .ToList()
            .Select(cg =>
             new SelectListItem
             {
               Text = (cg.Name).Trim(),
               Value = cg.Id.ToString()
             }).ToList()  ;

        }
      }
```

I needed to add `ToList()` after the join, and then again after converting to SelectlistItem. I also didnt need th create the new anonymous type - Thanks to joanna above for that.

This is the answer but not a good explanation, if anyone wants to pad it out a little please feel free!